# Can I cancel a long Arte?

Tags: tales-of-arise

I am fighting against Earthen Mass enemies who are weak to Wind. However using Alphen's Orochi's Galeforce Fury, which is a wind arte, means I can be hit and knocked out of the arte by enemies. It is a three hit arte which has a total animation time of about 2 seconds.

Is there a way for me to cancel an arte or interrupt it to dodge? Or do I have to time my arte usage based on the enemies attack patterns?

I am playing on semi-auto battle mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to cancel an arte once you start it. The only variant of this is Rinwell is able to store artes and move around once charged and Kisara is able to move while guarding (once unlocked in the skill tree). Other than that, you will always finish the entire arte once you start it.